# Entity data source. Add new record. How to "seek" first to see if there before

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-web-developer

New with EDS. VWD 2011.

Adding vehicles to my vehicle file. PK is Company number (char 5) and vehicle code (char 15).  Using a details view with only the main keys and the entitydatasource is defined and working with datakeynames.

In the EDS inserting event, i want to go into the file, and see if what is entered, is there first.  It adds perfect if a new code, and of course bombs is duplicate.

Old visual foxpro programmer, just learning this. The EDS is already opened with the correct file in the database and everything..  maybe if I do a count() "where" condition, and if 0, maybe new... I really just want some foxpro SEEK COMPANYNUMBER+VEHCODE and if not there, allow to add...

Thanks for any input. It is 2:19am in the morning.. fun teaching myself something new...lots of hours.. 
Frank C :)

Comment: Maybe reread this question after a good night's rest an try to imagine what someone else would understand of it.

Answer (score 0):

You 'could' go out and check to see if the record already exists, and than add it only if it does not; perhaps a better way is to have a unique index on that field combination so that it would be impossible to save duplicate records, and then let EF tell you when the save changes has failed. This will prevent you from making two calls to the DB on every insert attempt.

Example:

```
    try
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Vehicles.Add(vehicle);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
catch (DataException)
{
    //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
}
```